MacOS Sonoma and Chrome: the window title bar hides the tabs of Chrome when the cursor overs on top of the screen
I see that in the video included in the following question that the tabs move down when over on top of the screen (which some people seems to dislike): Make the Menu Bar never show while in Full Screen
In my case, instead the tabs moving down, it's super uncomfortable because the tabs are hidden by the window title bar when I over the mouse on top:

This may be a solution to the problem (which maybe it's not a possible solution though: at the moment it's without a reply anyways): How to disable the title bar in fullscreen?
So: how to avoid that the title bar hides the Chrome tabs when I hover on top (which is 50% of the times I want to click in a tab: common headache).

Believe it or not, I found a brilliant solution a few seconds after publishing this question! :D
The solution (I copy and paste):

chrome://flags/#enable-immersive-fullscreen-toolbar
Go to this Chrome flag (just copy and paste into the URL) and turn it
to Enable

So now, when I over on top:

Found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookpro/comments/17g9ov3/comment/kkak908/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

How about Firefox?
